# How to limit Woocommerce search to titles only?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I used to have a snippet that limits search results to titles only, but with recent updates it doesn't work any more.
It will be great it of somebody can help here out, for me and others that looking for a solution to this.
Thanks
D

EDIT:
That's the old code:

```php
// Search by Title only!
function __search_by_title_only( $search, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if(empty($search)) {
        return $search; // skip processing - no search term in query
    }
    $q = $wp_query->query_vars;
    $n = !empty($q['exact']) ? '' : '%';
    $search =
    $searchand = '';
    foreach ((array)$q['search_terms'] as $term) {
        $term = esc_sql($wpdb->esc_like($term));
        $search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
        $searchand = ' AND ';
    }
    if (!empty($search)) {
        $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
        if (!is_user_logged_in())
            $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
    }
    return $search;
}
add_filter('posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 500, 2);
```

Comment: Where is the snippet? Is it WooCommerce-only (which is off-topic) or it worked without it?

Comment: I'm not sure - I think it is for woocommerce, here is it anyway. Just keep in mind it doesn't work with latest versions of wc and wp.

Comment: The snippet works perfectly with the currently last versions of WordPress (5.2.2) and WooCommerce (3.6.5). WooCommerce. And it's not WooCommerce-only.